# AngularJS Ui Router, handle query string regexp mismatch

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to ask for some help. 
I have url template like `url: "/foo?{boo:[1-3]}{zoo:[1-2]}"`.
But then happens query params regexp mismatch, nothing is happening. Just a white blank page, no any errors or `otherwise` event firing .
How can i handle this mismatch?
Ui-router of last version.

With best regards. Thanks for your attention.